# MediaPlayer audio doesn't stop immediately when stop() is called

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

A button has onClickMethod openTheLock() which makes an ImageView visible and starts an audio. On tapping on the ImageView it disappears and the audio stops. Audio is initialized in onCreate(). The problem is the audio doesn't stop immediately when the ImageView is tapped. What could be the reason?

```
MediaPlayer jokerAudio;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_earth_room);
        jokerAudio= MediaPlayer.create(EarthRoomActivity.this, R.raw.joker_laugh);
    }
public void openTheLock(View v){
    if(selectedItem == R.id.key_er_item || keyUsed == true){
    jokerAudio.start();
    ImageView joker = (ImageView)parentLayout.findViewById(R.id.joker);
    joker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    joker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            jokerAudio.stop();
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);         
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: move the joker code to `onCreate` and try and what is `parentLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using the `MediaPlayer` again then you can try releasing the `MediaPlayer`.

```
joker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            jokerAudio.stop();
            jokerAudio.reset();
            jokerAudio.release();
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);         
        }
    });
```

However if you are using `MediaPlayer` again later in your code don't forget to reinitialize it again.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the audio again, that's why I didn't release. However, I tried what you said. If I just reset and release it works, but if I transfer  jokerAudio= MediaPlayer.create(EarthRoomActivity.this, R.raw.joker_laugh); inside the openTheLock method, so that it is created on every button click the original problem appears

Comment: Try making it local...Define like this in openTheLock method `MediaPlayer jokerAudio = MediaPlayer.create(EarthRoomActivity.this, R.raw.joker_laugh);` and remove the global jokerAudio object.

Comment: Hey, thanks, it helped! Although I have no idea why. Would you care to explain please?

Comment: Also if you could edit your answer to full, I would accept it.